# stopping a UIScrollView at a specific position

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

Im trying to implement a horizontal scroll view for an iPad app. The scroll view shows a series of images. After scrolling, when the scroll view stops I want the images to be aligned along specific points along the horizontal. To do this I tried 2 approaches:

1) Disable scrolling for the UIScrollView and instead implement a PanGestureRecogniser which would detect the translation and velocity of the "swipe/drag" motion and set the content offset of the scroll view accordingly to the required pre-determined points. But, the problem here is that if the user slowly drags the scroll view, the scroll view motion is very jerky because the retrieved x co-ordinated of the scroll view jump back and forth around the point the finger is pressed. For eg: x values goes from 50 to 70 when the finger moves along 60-70. How can i make the motion of the scroll view smooth?

2) Enable scrolling for the UIScrollView and check the end of deceleration and then set the content offset of the scroll view to adjust it to the necessary position. But the problem here is that the scroll view adjusts to its final position only after it stops decelerating and there is a visible delay and this animation does not look good too. Is there a way that i can detect when the scroll view is about to stop scrolling and then adjust its position instead of waiting it to end scrolling. From what iv read on some forums this wont be possible.

3) A paging scrollview will not work in this scenario as I dont want the entire width of images to be scrolled out.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can implement the above functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same problem with a `vertical` `scrollview` and used the approach 2. Even if this question is old, I didn't find a solution here and felt it would be great to answer.

The short answer is the `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`
method in `UIScrollViewDelegate` `protocol`.

It gives you the `targetContentOffset` when the user finishes scrolling and the animation start decelerating. You can change the `targetContentOffset` in this method, so the `animation` will end exactly where you can. Your job is only to calculate the target position.

Here's the `UIView` subclass I've created. I wanted to create a `UIPickerView` like class, but I wanted it to stop on specific positions (like the date picker).

I created an `UIView` subclass that conformed to `UIScrollViewDelegate`. In this `UIView`, I did add a `scrollView`. This `scrollView` will contain `UILabel` instances. Be careful, I use `ARC`, so I do not release anything.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MyPickerViewDataSource <NSObject>

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRowsForSender:(id)sender;
-(NSString *)titleForRowAtIndex:(NSUInteger)rowIndex sender:(id)sender;

@end

@interface MyPickerView : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<MyPickerViewDataSource> dataSource;

@end
```

The implementation :

```
#import "MyPickerView.h"

#define CONTENT_ROW_HEIGHT 30

typedef enum {
    ScrollDirectionUp,
    ScrollDirectionDown
} ScrollDirection;

@interface MyPickerView() {

    int topOffset;
    int bottomOffset;
    int lastContentOffset;
    int targetLabelIndex;
    ScrollDirection scrollDirection;
}

@implementation PickerView

- (void)initSetup {
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self addSubview:self.scrollView];

targetLabelIndex = 0;

topOffset = (self.scrollView.frame.size.height/2)-CONTENT_ROW_HEIGHT/2;
bottomOffset = topOffset;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self) {
        [self initSetup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self) {
        [self initSetup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSUInteger numberOfRows = [self.dataSource numberOfRowsForSender:self];

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, topOffset+numberOfRows*CONTENT_ROW_HEIGHT+bottomOffset);

    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfRows; index++)
    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.origin.x,
                                                                   topOffset+index*CONTENT_ROW_HEIGHT,
                                                                   self.scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                                                   CONTENT_ROW_HEIGHT)];

        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
        label.text = [self.dataSource titleForRowAtIndex:index sender:self];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:label];
    }

    [(UILabel *)[self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:targetLabelIndex] setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}

- (void)reloadData {

    NSUInteger numberOfRows = [self.dataSource numberOfRowsForSender:self];

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, numberOfRows*CONTENT_ROW_HEIGHT);

    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) animated:NO];

    [self layoutSubviews];
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if(lastContentOffset>self.scrollView.contentOffset.y) {

        scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionUp;
    }
    else {

        scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionDown;
    }

    lastContentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {

    targetLabelIndex = (targetContentOffset->y/CONTENT_ROW_HEIGHT)+1;

    if(scrollDirection==ScrollDirectionUp && targetLabelIndex>0) {

        targetLabelIndex--;
    }

    targetContentOffset->y = targetLabelIndex*CONTENT_ROW_HEIGHT;

    [(UILabel *)[self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:targetLabelIndex] setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this; I ran into the same problem with a UICollectionView. I note that the method documentation suggests this approach: "Your application can change the value of the targetContentOffset parameter to adjust where the scrollview finishes its scrolling animation."

Answer (score 1):

You can actually still use a paging scroll view to do this. All you need to do is set `clipsToBounds` to `NO` (so that the contents in the scroll view are allowed to render outside its frame), and then set the `frame` to the desired alignment steps.

For example, if you want to align the scroll view on multiples of 200, you could do this:

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;

// horizontally center scroll view with a width of 200 and the parent's height
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(
    floor((parentView.bounds.size.width - 200) / 2),
    0,
    200,
    parentView.bounds.size.height
);

[parentView addSubview:scrollView];
```

Comment: True. But in this case wont the "scrollable/swipe-able" area also be restricted to a width of 200? That means the user will not be able to swipe across the full horizontal portion that the images are rendered in and will be restricted to scrolling/swiping only within those 200 units. I want the user to be able to scroll across the entire width of the scroll view.

Comment: You might be able to circumvent this issue by subclassing `UIScrollView` and overriding `hitTest:withEvent:` to return `YES` for anything within the area you want scrollable (the full width of the parent view, in this case).

Comment: Ok I should try that. But, with a Paging scroll view comes another fundamental issue. If the user makes a "quick swipe" then only one image(or a fixed set of images) would scroll out each time right? It would not be like a free scroll-view where the number of images getting scrolled out each time would vary according to the distance and speed of the swipe. Sorry if it looks like im playing the devil's advocate here but im just trying to get the functionality right.

Comment: @Nathan From a UX perspective, if your scroll view is going to be aligned along certain points, that's actually the interaction you want. I would argue that the user should be able to make a quick swipe to just move left or right by one item, since that's the standard paradigm defined for "aligned" or paging scroll views.

Comment: But the functionality im trying to implement here is similar to the "Wired" magazine's iPad app. In that, they have a thumbnail scroll view which implements the functionality im talking about. I do not think they are using a paging scroll view, and the thumbnails in their scroll view do get aligned at specific points along the horizontal.